# Pandas not importing when run in visual studio code command line?

Tags: pandas, visual-studio

I'm running a simple .py file that only contains

```
import pandas as pd
```

in the visual studio code terminal on my desktop and I get this error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas', but when I run

```
import pandas as pd
```

in a cell in a .ipynb file in visual studio in the same directory it runs fine. What might be the problem here?

UPDATE: In fact, simply running

```
python3 test.py
```

in the terminal runs the code perfectly. So I seem to be not understanding something about how to use the visual studio code terminal

Comment: This isn't going to be a perfect explanation since I don't have perfect understanding (hence why it's a comment) but ipynb requires a kernel to run, which is usually a virtual environment that may or may not be different from the root installation of python that you have. You can solve this by running the specific virtual environment you use for your ipynb files in the terminal, or installing pandas on your root environment

Comment: Interesting, but would this explain why running 'python3 test.py' in the terminal works ?

Comment: Does your update mean this is now solved: "running `python3 test.py` in the terminal runs the code perfectly"

Comment: No sorry I should clarify. Running it in the command line terminal of my computer solves the problem. Running it in the visual studio code terminal still throws the same error.